# PHP string replacement regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have date in following format **07 Dec, 2010**. I need to convert it to **07_Dec_2010**.

How can I achieve following using **single statement**

Help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newString = preg_replace('/\W+/', '_', $oldString);
```

This will replace any one or more non-word characters with a single underscore

Comment: does preg_replace have any compatibility issue like it works only on PHP 5 or something else?

Comment: @IMJM Best place to check is the manual (also, you don't need to ask the same question more than once)

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdate = preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', '_', '07 Dec, 2010');
```

Comment: does preg_replace have any compatibility issue like it works only on PHP 5 or something else?

Comment: @Rafe You're missing the regex delimeters around the pattern

Comment: @PhilBrown thanks, that bit of PHP always mixes me up (never really got why that was necessary coming from Python)

Comment: @Rafe I hear you. I'd say it's because regular expressions aren't first class citizens in PHP, yet it still needs something to pass to the PCRE engine

Comment: @PhilBrown regex aren't first class in Python either, but you can just pass a string to a regex function and it works that way. Dunno, a lot of the quirks of PHP syntax make no sense to me (why make everything ugly by requiring a sigil for a variable). It's all old perl stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('d_M_Y',strtotime('07 Dec, 2010'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdate = str_replace( ' ', '_', str_replace( ',','', "07 Dec, 2010" ) );
```

**Edit:**

```
$newdate = str_replace( array(',' , ' '), array('' , '_'), "07 Dec, 2010" );
```

Comment: @downvoter: I will feel happy if you will tell me a reason and I will learn something new.

Comment: @pinaki: Are you sure? `,` is removed before replacing space with `_`. http://codepad.org/d15A7aDd

Comment: @pinaki: You still did not justify your comments.

Comment: @NAVEED - you are right.. i think i confused the second blank with a underscore the other night; extremely sorry about that. 

On another note, i agree this does what is required, but is it one line? The OP wanted the change in a "single statement" and you have two statements there. I am not sure having multiple function calls in one-line can be termed as a single statement.

Comment: @pinaki: Ok. I have edited my answer. Will you consider it as a single statement.